# ZK drag and drop and databinding

Tags: java, web, zk

I'm having a problem with ZK binding and drag and drop feature.
I have two listboxes:

```
<listbox id="left" width="100%" model="@load(vm.contacts)" height="200px" draggable="true" droppable="true" onDrop="@command('move')">                      
    <listhead>
        <listheader label="Contatto" align="center"  />
    </listhead>
    <template name="model" var="contact">
        <listitem value="@bind(contact)" draggable="true" droppable="true" onDrop="@command('move')"> 
           <listcell src="/img/contact-icon_x32.jpg" label="@load(contact.person.surname.concat(' ').concat(contact.person.name))" />
        </listitem>
    </template>
</listbox>
...
<listbox width="100%" id="right" model="@load(vm.contactsQuickKey)" height="250px" draggable="true" droppable="true" onDrop="@command('move')" >
    <listhead>
         <listheader label="Etichetta" align="center"  />
         <listheader label="Contatto" align="center"  />
    </listhead>
    <template name="model" var="contactQuickKey">
         <listitem value="@bind(contactQuickKey)" draggable="true" droppable="true" onDrop="@command('move')">
             <listcell>                                   
                 <textbox width="90%" value="@load(contactQuickKey.label) @save(contactQuickKey.label, before={'move', 'saveData', 'setLeftActivePage'})"/>
             </listcell>
             <listcell src="/img/contact-icon_x32.jpg" label="@load(contactQuickKey.contact.person.surname.concat(' ').concat(contactQuickKey.contact.person.name))" />
         </listitem>
    </template>
</listbox>
```

If I edit the textbox in the right listbox and then immediately, without clicking anywhere, I drag and drop a cell from the left one, the text I added disappears. 
The only way I can save the text is to use an onchange event, but it is very heavy.

**EDIT**:
I created a working demo here http://zkfiddle.org/sample/2t6r27o/24-drag-and-drop-test

Does anyone can give me a better solution?

Thank you very much!

**SOLUTION**

I added the "instant="true"" to the textbox and this solved my problem!

Thanks to all of you how helped me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to put the  `instant="true"`  to the **textbox**. This solved the problem of losing text modification with a drag and drop.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is, that your text ist not loaded into the serverside `Textbox`.
You save before drop by `before={'move'...` but you can't load it into
the `Textbox`, cos this needs a `notifyChange`, which is fullfilled before
`@command('move')` is executed and this is not possible, cos of the zk 
execution cycle and the fact that `move` causes the save

What you could do is, chage the `Textbox` manually from the data in your
vm class at the `move` command. But it could maybe a problem to figure out
to which instance of `contactQuickKey` the dragged `Textbox` belongs.

By the way, where is the problem with onChanging? The traffic shouldn't be one.

### Edit

For some reason the data is not saved before the `move` command, if
not another user action occurs before the drag.
Maybe a bug?

Comment: The onchanging is very slow and if I delete with the backspace key a lot of text and then try to write other text, I don't know why but the textbox loses focus. Probably the fact that the text is not saved before the move command could be a bug, but I don't find anyone else having this problem, so I'm still wondering if it is something wrong in my code.

Comment: The problem with the focus you could maybe solve by checking the case of empty string and if it is so call `((Textbox)event.getTarget).focus()`

Comment: The same if the string is not completely empty: the textbox loses focus. This behavior happens also if I stop to write text for a second.